# Embeddable python enviroment - external modules

Tags: python, c++, installation, pip, pybind11

I'm writting an application in `c++` which uses `pybind11` library to provide `python` support.

I use some non standard python libraries installed with `pip`.

Now I'd like to build a Windows installer which would contain complete application with all required python modules and proper python environment.

I add extracted python-embed.zip provided by https://www.python.org/ but it lacks of modules which are required by external modules I use.

For example one of modules I use in my application requires `pkg_resources`.
I would add it with `pip` to my installation, but there are no modules available for `pip` matching this name.

I'm not sure how to solve these problems in right way.

Comment: Where does the `uio` module come from?

Comment: Oh, it is here by accident - I've tried to use `micropython-pkg_resources` instead of `pkg_resources` and that package required `uid`. Original `pkg_resources` doesn't require `uio`.

Comment: @hoefling I have modified the question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: The embedded interpreter has its own rules, e.g. it ignores the env completely (since Python 3.6) and the installed scripts reference the interpreter executable by absolute path, so the best approach is to download the wheels for modules in question, include them in the installer (caution - if you have lots of dependencies, the installer may become quite big) and install the modules while installing the interpreter. I have examples of distributing an embedded interpreter with third-party packages in an NSIS installer; if this is your case, I can post some code in the answer to help you out.

Comment: I cannot find wheels for packages I use in google. They provide `setup.py` file but without `bdist_wheel` command, which as far as I understand is required for building a wheel. I guess I can try to patch it to provide proper command. However I am still not sure how `pkg_resources` module will be included. Anyway you can show me your configuration for NSIS installer as I'm using it too. It will be helpful for sure.

Comment: You can use source dists instead of wheels, although wheels are of course preferrable as they don't require code execution to be installed (it's a simple unzipping + metadata generation). You can also generate wheels locally - download source dist file and run `pip wheel mypkg-1.0.tar.gz`, then include `mypkg-1.0-py3-None-any.whl` in the installer.

Comment: Also, beware that source dists with C extension modules will not generate you a platform-independent wheel.

Comment: @hoefling I still wonder if that will help my with my original problem - missing `pkg_resources` in embeddable python.

Comment: `pkg_resources` is part of the `setuptools` package and isn't part of any Python distribution. It must be installed in a separate step.

Comment: @hoefling Thx, that was the missing part. You can turn your comments into answer so I can accept it. Also You can share your NSIS tips.